# Internationalization of content in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, internationalization

I keep coming across an i18n requirement where my data (not my UI) needs to be internationalized.

```
public class FooEntity
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string Code { get; set; } // Some values might not need i18n
  public string Name { get; set } // but e.g. this needs internationalized
  public string Description { get; set; } // and this too
}
```

**What are some approaches I could use?**

**Some things I've tried:-**

**1) Store a resource key in the db**

```
public class FooEntity
{
  ...
  public string NameKey { get; set; }
  public string DescriptionKey { get; set; }
}
```

- Pros: No need for complicated queries to get a translated entity. `System.Globalization` handles fallbacks for you.
- Cons: Translations can't easily be managed by an admin user (have to deploy resource files whenever my `Foo`s change).

**2) Use a `LocalizableString` entity type**

```
public class FooEntity
{
  ...

  public int NameId { get; set; }
  public virtual LocalizableString Name { get; set; }

  public int NameId { get; set; }
  public virtual LocalizableString Description { get; set; }
}

public class LocalizableString
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public ICollection<LocalizedString> LocalizedStrings { get; set; }
}

public class LocalizedString
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int ParentId { get; set; }
  public virtual LocalizableString Parent { get; set; }

  public int LanguageId { get; set; }
  public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

  public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string CultureCode { get; set; }
}
```

- Pros: All localised strings in the same table. Validation can be performed per-string.
- Cons: Queries are horrid. Have to .Include the LocalizedStrings table once for each localizable string on the parent entity. Fallbacks are hard and involve extensive joining. Haven't found a way to avoid N+1 when retrieving e.g. data for a table.

**3) Use a parent entity with all the invariant properties and child entities containing all the localized properties**

```
public class FooEntity
{
  ...
  public ICollection<FooTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class FooTranslation
{
  public long Id { get; set; }

  public int ParentId { get; set; }
  public virtual FooEntity Parent { get; set; }

  public int LanguageId { get; set; }
  public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string CultureCode { get; set; }
}
```

- Pros: Not as hard (but still too hard!) to get a full translation of an entity into memory.
- Cons: Double the number of entities. Can't handle partial translations of an entity - especially the case where, say, Name is coming from `es` but Description is coming from `es-AR`.

**I have three requirements for a solution**

- Users can edit entities, languages, and translations at runtime
- Users can supply partial translations with missing strings coming from a fallback as per System.Globalization
- Entities can be brought into memory without running into e.g. N+1 issues

Comment: Still not answered, I was interested too.

Comment: It's not clear what you would consider an acceptable answer.If somebody has an option 4 it's likely to have pros/cons too.

Comment: Clarified question. I don't expect there to be a perfect solution, but hopefully there's one better than I've come up with so far.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take the best of both worlds?
Have a CustomResourceManager that handles the loading of resources and picking the right culture and use a CustomResourceReader that uses whatever backing store you like. A basic implementation could look like this, relying on convention of the Resourceky being Typename_PropertyName_PropertyValue. If for some reason the structure of the backingstore(csv/excel/mssql/table structure) need to change you only have the change the implementation of the ResourceReader.

As an added bonus I also got the real/transparent proxy going.

**ResourceManager**

```
class MyRM:ResourceManager
{
    readonly Dictionary<CultureInfo, ResourceSet>  sets = new Dictionary<CultureInfo, ResourceSet>();


    public void UnCache(CultureInfo ci)
    {
        sets.Remove(ci):
    }

    protected override ResourceSet InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, bool createIfNotExists, bool tryParents)
    {
        ResourceSet set;
        if (!sets.TryGetValue(culture, out set))
        {
            IResourceReader rdr = new MyRR(culture);
            set = new ResourceSet(rdr);
            sets.Add(culture,set);
        }
        return set; 
    }

    // sets Localized values on properties
    public T GetEntity<T>(T obj)
    {
        var entityType = typeof(T);
        foreach (var prop in entityType.GetProperties(
                    BindingFlags.Instance   
                    | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) 
                && p.CanWrite 
                && p.CanRead))
        {
            // FooEntity_Name_(content of Name field)
            var key = String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", 
                entityType.Name, 
                prop.Name, 
                prop.GetValue(obj,null));

            var val = GetString(key);
            // only set if a value was found
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
            {
                prop.SetValue(obj, val, null);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

**ResourceReader**

```
class MyRR:IResourceReader
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _dict;

    public MyRR(CultureInfo ci)
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // get from some storage (here a hardcoded Dictionary)
        // You have to be able to deliver a IDictionaryEnumerator
        switch (ci.Name)
        {
            case "nl-NL":
                _dict.Add("FooEntity_Name_Dutch", "nederlands");
                _dict.Add("FooEntity_Name_German", "duits");
                break;
            case "en-US":
                _dict.Add("FooEntity_Name_Dutch", "The Netherlands");
                break;
            case "en":
                _dict.Add("FooEntity_Name_Dutch", "undutchables");
                _dict.Add("FooEntity_Name_German", "german");
                break;
            case "": // invariant
                _dict.Add("FooEntity_Name_Dutch", "dutch");
                _dict.Add("FooEntity_Name_German", "german?");
                break;
            default:
                Trace.WriteLine(ci.Name+" has no resources");
                break;
        }

    }

    public System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dict.GetEnumerator();
    }
    // left out not implemented interface members
  }
```

**Usage**

```
var rm = new MyRM(); 

var f = new FooEntity();
f.Name = "Dutch";
var fl = rm.GetEntity(f);
Console.WriteLine(f.Name);

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");

f.Name = "Dutch";
var dl = rm.GetEntity(f);
Console.WriteLine(f.Name);
```

**RealProxy**

```
public class Localizer<T>: RealProxy
{
    MyRM rm = new MyRM();
    private T obj; 

    public Localizer(T o)
        : base(typeof(T))
    {
        obj = o;
    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        var meth = msg.Properties["__MethodName"].ToString();
        var bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance ;
        if (meth.StartsWith("set_"))
        {
            meth = meth.Substring(4);
            bf |= BindingFlags.SetProperty;
        }
        if (meth.StartsWith("get_"))
        {
           // get the value...
            meth = meth.Substring(4);
            var key = String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}",
                                    typeof (T).Name,
                                    meth,
                                    typeof (T).GetProperty(meth, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance
        |BindingFlags.GetProperty).
        GetValue(obj, null));
            // but use it for a localized lookup (rm is the ResourceManager)
            var val = rm.GetString(key);
            // return the localized value
            return new ReturnMessage(val, null, 0, null, null);
        }
        var args = new object[0];
        if (msg.Properties["__Args"] != null)
        {
            args = (object[]) msg.Properties["__Args"];
        }
        var res = typeof (T).InvokeMember(meth, 
            bf
            , null, obj, args);
        return new ReturnMessage(res, null, 0, null, null);
    }
}
```

**Real/Transparent proxy usage**

```
 var f = new FooEntity();
 f.Name = "Dutch";
 var l = new Localizer<FooEntity>(f);
 var fp = (FooEntity) l.GetTransparentProxy();
 fp.Name = "Dutch"; // notice you can use the proxy as is,
                    // it updates the actual FooEntity
 var localizedValue = fp.Name;
```

Comment: I'm worried about the query characteristics of this solution. If I'm not mistaken, either I need to load all the localized strings in the application into memory (with all the issues that come with that), or I need to call MyRM.GetEntity on each individual entity - which is going to cause serious N+1 issues when I want to display a table of entities.

Comment: It depends. If memory pressure is your concern you could implement a smart caching solution that remove resourceSets from memory after x time. Or are there more issues I don't oversee now? And you're correct that you have to call GetEntity on each entity. But it is either that or have a complex query. One thing I tried but couldn't get working was either a dynamic or transparentproxy that exposes localized results from your properties. That integrates the localized entity in any current code seamlessly. And you can then focus on a technical implementation that satifies your requirements.

Comment: The more pressing issue, I think, is cleanly ensuring that this cache gets invalidated when the remote read store gets updated.

Comment: Can you have a [SqlCacheDependancy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx) in your architecture?

Comment: Is a business requirement that after changing one single value that value is immediately served in the live app? Or could they live with a delay of a couple of hours?

Comment: I added an UnCache method to at least make it possible to clear the cache for a specific culture...

Answer (score 1):

**First one** is worthy if you have static content in database. For example if you have *categories* that relatively are not going to be changed by user. You can change them at next deploy. I do not like this solution personally. I do not consider this as a nice solution. This is just an escape of the problem.

**Second one** is the best but can cause a problem when you have two or more localizable fields in one entity. You can simplify it a bit and hard code languages on it like this

```
public class LocalizedString
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string EnglishText { get; set; }
  public string ItalianText { get; set; }
  public string ArmenianText { get; set; }
}
```

**Third one** is not a good one neither. From this structure I can't be sure that all nodes (literals, lines, strings etc.) translated in specific culture.

Do not generalize too much. Each problem is kind of specialized and it needs specialized solution too. Too much generalization makes unjustified issues.

Comment: I don't fancy de-normalising the LocalizedString entity as this'll mean admin users won't be able to add new languages. I don't think this is a "generalising too much" problem. This is a genuine business problem - my users often need to be able to edit entities, languages, translations without the intervention of a developer.

Comment: Sorry I was not understood you correctly. I was not know that you want to be able to add languages as well.