# Globalization and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, localization

I have a project where most of the globalization Information is stored in the resx. files and Dataannotations are extensively used.

But now there is a new Poco class which has a text which needs to be localized. What is the best method to do this?

I would do it like this:

```
public class example
{
  public int ItemID {get; set;}

  public string Description_en_US {get; set;}

  public string Description_de_DE {get; set;}
}
```

My main concern is how to use this later on in the razor webpage, maybe I will build a method who select a column depending on the thread locale - or does some better mechanism exist?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085205/internationalization-of-content-in-entity-framework

Comment: you are correct, I tried to find such a thread, but never found one. Thanks!